# get target vector from simplex optimisation in R

Tags: r, object, vector, simplex-algorithm

I started using R to solve a LP-Problem using the simplex funciton from library("boot"). When i try the following code I only get the target vector as string but not as a vector.

```
library("boot") 
# This example is taken from Exercise 7.5 of Gill, Murray and Wright (1991).
enj <- c(200, 6000, 3000, -200)
fat <- c(800, 6000, 1000, 400)
vitx <- c(50, 3, 150, 100)
vity <- c(10, 10, 75, 100)
vitz <- c(150, 35, 75, 5)
j<-simplex(a = enj, A1 = fat, b1 = 13800, A2 = rbind(vitx, vity, vitz),
b2 = c(600, 300, 550), maxi = TRUE)
xx<-(j["soln"])
print(xx)
```

From this get the folling output

```
$soln
x1   x2   x3   x4 
0.0  0.0 13.8  0.0
```

However, this is not a vector object so i can't get the Element of the first Dimension by using `x[1]`. Can you please help me to get the result as a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `xx` is a list so it's quite easy to return a specific value within it.

For example, if you want x1, you can do :

`xx[["soln"]]["x1"]` or `xx[[1]][1]`

But if you want to transform `xx` into a vector, you can do :

```
xx2 <- unlist(xx)
```

and then you have a vector :

```
> xx2
soln.x1 soln.x2 soln.x3 soln.x4 
    0.0     0.0    13.8     0.0 

> is.vector(xx2)
[1] TRUE
```

If you don't want to keep the names for each element in the vector, put the arg `use.names` to `FALSE` :

```
> xx2 <- unlist(xx, use.names = FALSE)
> xx2
[1]  0.0  0.0 13.8  0.0

> is.vector(xx2)
[1] TRUE
```